# How to echo random amounts of dots mixed with spaces?

Tags: bash, terminal

I would like bash/terminal command to make it echo

```
 ...  . . . .  . .  ..  ...... .. . . .
```

in other words random amounts of dots perhaps 100 dots max, mixed with spaces.

how can this be done via bash script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```
max=$((RANDOM%100)); for ((i=0;i<max;i++)); do ((RANDOM%2)) && a="$a." || a="$a "; done; echo "$a"
```

or in a more readable format:

```
max=$((RANDOM%100))
for ((i=0;i<max;i++))
do 
    ((RANDOM%2)) && a="$a." || a="$a "
done
echo "$a"
```

Comment: can this be assigned to a letter such as "a" so i can run echo "$a"

Answer (score 6):

If you want the line to be *really* random, say:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '. ' | fold -w 100 | head -1
```

For assigning it to a variable, say:

```
foo=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '. ' | fold -w 100 | head -1)
```

A sample output would look like:

```
  ......   .  . .     .......  .  ...    .....   . ... .  .  .  . .    ..   .... .   .  . .  ... . .
```

Simply saying:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '. ' | fold -w 100
```

would produce *endless* lines of random data that are 100 characters wide until you interrupt.

Comment: Facing an issue (on ubuntu, kernel 3.2.0-27): `head -1` does not stop the cat command, with sigpipe or anything. So it just print 1st line & then keeps waiting for `^C`. piping through `pv` shows that the data is still flowing. Possible workaround is `read -n 100  foo < <(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '. ')`. It however, gives `write error: broken pipe` message, but does terminate the command.

Comment: @anishsane That's odd.  `head -1` should send a `SIGPIPE` to `cat` after reading one line.

Comment: It works on one system (redhat based), but on ubuntu 13.04, with kernel 3.2.0-27, it is not sending sigpipe. Not sure why. Hence added the workaround in a comment, in case it is useful to someone...

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..100}; do
    even=$(( $RANDOM % 2 ))
    if [ $even -eq 0 ]; then
            printf " ";
    else
            printf "." 
    fi  
done

printf "\n"
```

Or as asked in the comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=$(
    for i in {1..100}; do
            even=$(( $RANDOM % 2 ))
            if [ $even -eq 0 ]; then
                    printf " ";
            else
                    printf "."
            fi
    done
    printf "\n"
)

echo $a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ x='. '; for i in {1..100}; do printf "${x:$((RANDOM%2)):1}"; done && echo
 . .. ...   .....  .. .   .. .    .. .   .. . ...  .....  . . ..  ... . . .  .. .. ..    .. . .....
```

That way you can also easily influence the dot-to-space ratio by doing e.g. `x='.... '` and using `$RANDOM % 5`

```
$ x='.... '; for i in {1..100}; do printf "${x:$((RANDOM%5)):1}"; done && echo
.................. ... ...... . .  ..... .     ........ . ....    ............ ........... .. .  ...
```

or add other characters to your output

```
$ x='abc '; for i in {1..100}; do printf "${x:$(($RANDOM%4)):1}"; done && echo
b a ccac  bb aac abbcccab aa   baabb cbbacbacb  cbab b a baccccaa bc  acc  cca ba cacccaaa  cbaba ab
```