# bash: integer to string, split and join with delimeter

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm newbie in 'sh'. Is it possible to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
i=123
i.to_s.split('').join('.') #=> "1.2.3"
```

I've tried something but didn't succeed:

```
i=123
IFS='' read -a array <<< "$i"
echo $array #=> "123"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `fold` and `paste`:

```
$ i=123
$ echo $i | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
1.2.3
$ i=1234567890
$ echo $i | fold -w1 | paste -sd.
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.0
```

Comment: I had thought of similar answer with `grep -o .`, instead of `fold -w1`, but fold is better option.

Comment: @anishsane Yes, you could use `grep` as you've said but `fold` if somewhat less known (but a pretty useful utility) ...

Comment: besides, this is the purpose `fold` was written for. `grep -o .` is just a way (read: misuse) to implement `fold` :-)

Comment: @anishsane You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18483504/2235132) for a somewhat _weird_ application of `fold`.

Comment: Seems a little obfuscated to me.  By reading the spec of `fold` and `paste` I would not have guessed that this use will achieve this goal.

Comment: @Alfe Could you please be specific about what part seems obfuscated about this?

Comment: `fold`: wrap each input line (I think about words there, but okay) and `paste`: merge lines of files (typically two or more files).  The idea behind the question was to _process_ a single line.  To split it into several lines and then combine those, that's not straight forward (albeit working, no doubt).  By reading about option `-s` in `man paste` I wouldn't have expected that result.  I learned sth by this, so thank you, but I would not use a solution in a professional environment which requires the next developer to first learn something ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Sorry, but I don't find this comment too constructive.  You are _prompting_ me to say that you expect one to be aware of extended regexps but not basic utilities on *nix systems that have existed since ...

Comment: Yeah, no, sorry, it is more a matter of taste I guess.  If I look up what `\B` does (or maybe I already know) then the working mechanism is straight forward: change all non-boundaries to dots.  And in your case I need to understand the mechanism and have to find out what the options do to twist the tools to work in that case.  But as I said, feel free to find my view subjective.  It is.

Comment: On mac, the `paste` command requires you to specify the input file (eg, stdin). Replace with `paste -sd. -`. Alternatively, you can use `tr '\n' '.'` but you might lose the trailing newline.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sed -r 's/\B/./g' <<< "$i"
```

Your `sed` needs to be able to handle extended regular expressions (option `-r`) for this, though.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that is using sed:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1./g' -e 's/\.$//' <<< "$i"
1.2.3
```